# Triggering CPLEX using Matlab

Tags: matlab, cplex

Is there any way to run a CPLEX OPL project using Matlab? Code will be written in CPLEX solver but it will be triggered (RUN) by Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not tried, this should be possible.  You can use [oplrun](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/refoplrun/topics/oplrun_TOP.html) to "execute OPL models and projects from the command line".  And, in MATLAB you can use [system](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) to "execute operating system command and return output".  Combining the two should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works with the combination and shows the execution. But now I'm facing another problem that is how to get the Decision Variables in the matlab work space. Could you please help me out?

Comment: I think you'd have to write the information to a text file from your OPL model and then read/parse it back in with MATLAB.  For example, see [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21508158) technote.  This is not ideal ... I'd seriously consider rewriting your model using one of the CPLEX API's instead.  The [docplex](https://developer.ibm.com/docloud/documentation/optimization-modeling/modeling-for-python/) modeling language is another option.