# How to run CPLEX from Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, cplex

Does anyone know how I can run a LP file in CPLEX from within a MATLAB script? I do NOT want to use The CPLEX® for MATLAB feature of IBM® ILOG® CPLEX Optimizers. Currently I do the following steps when I solve my problems:

1. Create an LP file in MATLAB
2. Export the LP file and solve it in CPLEX to get a SOL file
3. Copy the SOL file back to MATLAB, and extract the solution

So I would like a single MATLAB script to do all 3 steps.

Comment: This looks like a similar question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40296416

Answer (score 0):

You could use exec to call oplrun:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=d9a979f9-6885-440e-b5d6-08ced58b7b18&ps=25